# Drawing string diagrams using macros

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, diagrams

I am writing a paper which contains a lot of string diagrams from the type below. The problem is that many of them are complicated and it takes very much time to draw them from scratch. Is there a clever way how to draw them? Maybe using macros? Can anybody provide an example, please?

[image: Text]

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Did you see the `knots` package?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of that kind of figures, then the `knot` package should be used.

The following is another suggestion. I draw by hand each curve and put some nodes in appropriate position. Code is explained itself (I hope!).

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\rcurv{(1,0)--++(90:1) arc(180:0:.5) arc(180:360:.5)--++(90:1)}
\draw \rcurv ;
\draw[xscale=-1] \rcurv ;
\draw (0,0) node[below]{$(C)$}--+(90:2);
\path
(.5,1) node{=}
(-.5,1) node{=};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,0)--++(90:1) node[pos=.8,draw,fill=white]{$r$} 
arc(180:0:.5) arc(180:360:.5)--+(90:1);
\draw[xscale=-1] (1,0)--++(90:1) arc(180:0:.5) arc(180:360:.5)--+(90:1) node[pos=.2,draw,fill=white]{$r$};
\path (0,1) node{=} node[below=2mm]{$(I)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```